# Translated complex gaussian-type integral: $\int_0^{\infty} \exp(i(t-\alpha)^2) dt$

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

It's fairly straight forward to show that

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp(it^2) dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$

via complex contour integration over a contour shaped like a piece of pie:

[image: contour]

However, I am trying to determine the value of a similar integral with similar integrand where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\text{Im}(\alpha) < 0 $:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp(i(t-\alpha)^2) dt
$$

The above integral works nicely because along the top left curve, $t=r\exp(i\pi/4)$, so that $it^2 = -r^2$. I thought maybe I could set up the equation:
$$
i(r^2\exp(i2\theta)-\alpha)^2 = -r^2
$$
to determine some fixed $\theta$ (perhaps dependent on $\alpha$) along which to integrate, but this didn't really get me anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: If you expand the square in the exponent, you'll see a term $-2i\alpha t$. If $\operatorname{Im} \alpha > 0$, that screws up your integral badly, I think.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated to restrict $\alpha$.

Comment: The problem arises from the lower limit that renders a translational transformation ineffective.  The problem is then to evaluate $\int_{-\alpha}^{0}e^{it^2}dt$. So, the so-called imaginary error function is implicated.

Comment: @Dr.MV would you mind expanding on your comment more? In particular, how do you arrive at those bounds for the integral?

Comment: $t \to t-\alpha$.

Comment: Right. So, it's the top bound I'm unsure about. When this change of variables is made, we're now integrating over the contour $\left\{ -a+iy : y \in [-b,\infty) \right\}$. The im. error function integrates from the origin to some complex number, correct? How is this implied by this integral?

Comment: @Dr.MV I think I understand what you're saying now, but let me see if so... The integrand is holomorphic and thus the integral is path independent. So after change of variables the integral is equivalent to taking the path from $-\alpha$ to the origin, and then to infinity. The latter requires the im. error fcn, and so is not representable by elementary functions.

Comment: @chester Yes, you have it now!  Well done.

Comment: I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the Dr. MV's comments above as an answer:

If $\alpha = a+bi$, the change of variables $t \to t-\alpha$, changes the path of integration to the ray in the complex plane, $\left\{ -a+iy : y \in [-b,\infty) \right\}$. Since the integrand is holomorphic, the integral is path independent, and thus equivalent to integrating form $\alpha$ to the origin, and from the origin to $(-a,\infty)$. This requires the use of the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) which has no closed-form solution.

Answer (score 0):

By change of variables, the integral you are trying to evaluate is simply
$$
\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+\infty}e^{it^2}\ dt,
$$
which means "integrate along the horizontal ray starting at $\alpha$".

While you haven't provided your argument handling the case $\alpha=0$, you can adapt this argument to handle other $\alpha$ as well; the contour will shift, but should still wrap around the correct singularity (provided $\alpha$ belongs to a certain domain).

Comment: which singularity?!

Comment: I guess that's the point :)

Comment: That does not produce an answer in terms of elementary functions.  The imaginary error function is implicated in any case, except $\alpha=0$.